# ckeditor getData() does not return all the content

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

when I call getData() on a large amout of data I do not get all the content of ckeditor back. The data that is returned is truncated. Use firefox and go to the _samples/api.html add lots of content and click "Get Editior Contents" you will see the data is truncated. Can any help me with this as I need to be able to handle large document in ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WFM.

I pasted into editor content of samples site multiple times and `getData` returns entire content.

API sample uses `alert()` to display editor's content and OS/browser is truncating data so it fits on the screen. Please, check this in some JS console.